# Does TouchImageView support shrinking?

Tags: android

I have downloaded the sample code for TouchImageView and set the minScale to .80 to be able to shrink the image. This causes the image to align to the bottom or top of the screen, and not move fluently like when image is enlarged.

Source/Example
https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Is shrinking supported in Touchview? If not, is there a way to fix this?

Thanks,
Rune

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get shrinking working by adding the following to the onScale method

```
if (saveScale < 1){
    matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
}else if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
```

Problem is that dragging gets screwed up as soon as you do this.
To solve this in onTouch case:MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
Change the conditionals to do nothing when scaleWidth < width && scaleHeight < height.